# Preventing instantiation of unused default function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

Lets say I have a function which takes a function pointer as a parameter, and that parameter has a default argument.

```
template <typename T>
T* default_construct()
{
    return new T();
}

template <typename T>
void register(T* (*construct)() = default_construct<T>)
{
    // Save that function pointer for later
}
```

Lets say I want to use register on my class `Foo`, but `Foo` doesn't have a default constructor, so my `default_construct` won't work on it. The obvious solution is to do something like this:

```
Foo* construct_Foo()
{
    return new Foo("String argument", 123);
}

SomeFunc()
{
    // ...
    register<Foo>(construct_Foo);
    // ...
}
```

But that doesn't work. Even though `register<Foo>` may only be called in one place, and it's passed a function to use, `default_construct<Foo>` still gets instantiated by the compiler, and I get compiler errors. It seems like since it never gets used, it ought to be skipped over, but I guess that's not the case.

Is there any way to prevent `default_construct` from being instantiated when it's being used as a default argument? The only solution I can think of is to put it in the template, but it seems like there ought to be a better solution.

Comment: Are you sure that default_construct is instantiated? I honestly thought default parameters would be instantiated only if used. The following passed all compilers I tried: http://ideone.com/lHfSf

Comment: Following on UncleBens, you can inspect the symbols of the library/executable to check that a function template has been instanciated. Even though the name is mangled, `default_construct` should still appear. Use `nm somelib | grep default_construct` and use `c++filt` on the resulting symbols to get the expanded version.

Comment: UncleBens: You might be right after all. I was definitely getting an error that appeared to be caused by bad template instantiation, but I just tried again to show you the error message and this time I didn't get one. I must have done something else wrong, maybe this whole question is moot. Weird. (FWIW, I'm using gcc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one solution that solves the problem because it doesn't use default arguments:

```
template <typename T>
T* default_construct()
{
    return new T();
}

template <typename T>
void register(T* (*construct)())
{
    // Save that function pointer for later
}

template<typename T>
void register()
{
    register<T>(default_construct<T>);
}
```

Note that `register` is a C++ keyword though :)

Comment: doh! This is just an example though :P The actual function is luaW_register, but I didn't want to pull Lua into my question.

Comment: @Alex whenever default arguments come into play, just remember that they're only a shortcut for function overloading, and anything that can be done by default arguments and more can be done by overloading. And have fun with lua, it's awesome

Comment: I hadn't really thought of it that way, but I guess you're right. If you're interested, this is part of my attempt to improve [this](https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper) little Lua/c++ library I'm writing.

Comment: @Alex cool, what improvements are you making? And yeah, I hate using lua without a wrapper like that.

Comment: @Alex Oh, YOU wrote it. I thought you were improving someone else's wrapper (didn't realize you were the same Alex). That gets a bookmark, I'll definitely use it next time I use lua. Nice work.